# Join text files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to format the output of a `repadmin /showobjmetadata` script into a table for a while now in Powershell and the further I get, the more convoluted the script tends to be. Long story short, I'm at a point where I have 2 files I need to combine.

User.txt:

```
john doe
jane smith
generic name
```

data.txt:

```
Absent, <date>
Absent, <date>
Absent, <date>
```

I want to combine these files so they look like this:

```
Absent,<date>,John Doe
Absent,<date>,Jane Smith
Absent,<date>,generic name
```

in one single text document.

I've tried several `-join`, `foreach`, `New-object`, and `Select-String` approaches, but I'm getting nowhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many solutions, here's one (I assumed you deliberately removed the spaces before `<date>`):

```
$user = Get-Content "user.txt"
$data = Get-Content "data.txt"

$combined = for($count = 0; $count -lt $data.Count; $count++) {
    $dataWithoutSpaces = $data[$count] -replace " "
    "{0},{1}" -f $dataWithoutSpaces, $user[$count]
}

$combined | Out-File "result.txt"
```

result.txt:

```
Absent,<date>,john doe
Absent,<date>,jane smith
Absent,<date>,generic name
```

There must be some one-liners, I guess : ).

Comment: That did the trick! As long as it works with more than 3 lines of text in each file anyway. Thanks!